# Ubuntu OS selection screen doesn't Load

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP notebook laptop with preloaded Windows 8. Initially I was prompted to select an OS at boot but after 4-5 days it now doesn't give me this choice and automatically loads Windows.

How can I get back into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can find extensive help on this topic [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).